# java 8 stream group by and summing double

Tags: dictionary, java-8, grouping, java-stream, collectors

I am very new to streams in java 8 so my approach could be wrong.

I have 2 objects as follows

```
object1 {
    BigDecimal amount;
    Code1 code1;
    Code2 code2;
    Code3 code3;
    String desc;
}

object2 {
    BigDecimal amount;
    Code1 code1;
    Code2 code2;
    Code3 code3;
}
```

So I want to collect all object1 where code1 && code2 && code3 are same and then sum the amount add it to object2 list.

I do not have a code to do it...I want to write a code that does the job
I am trying to implement something from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Or compute the sum of all salaries by department:

```
// Compute sum of salaries by department
Map<Department, Integer> totalByDept = employees.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
Collectors.summingInt(Employee::getSalary)));
```

Comment: How could s sum of BigDecimals end up as a list of object2? Please show us REAL code.

Comment: Edited my question as per request.

Comment: So, what is the equivalent of the Department class? You need such a class to serve as key in the map, otherwise, you can't return a map.

Comment: Code1, code2 and code3 are actually classes ...i will edit it

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. By what do you want to group your objects?

Comment: Sorry,code1 && code2 && code3

Comment: So, you need a class MyKey, which contains these 3 attributes, and implements equals() and hashCode(), in order to be able to have a Map<MyKey, BigDecimal> as result.

Comment: will i have to create a key and refactor my objects to use that key?

Comment: To have a map, you need a key. Whether you use this key in your objects or not is up to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70644/discussion-between-ankit-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to JB Nizet for pointing me in the right direction.
I had to modify my object2

```
public class CodeSummary {
    Double amount;
    CodeKey key;
//getters and setters

}
public class CodeKey {
    String code1;
    String code2;
    String code3;
//getters and setters

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof CodeKey)) return false;

        CodeKey that = (CodeKey) o;

        if (!code1.equals(that.code1)) return false;
        if (!code2.equals(that.code2)) return false;
        if (!code3.equals(that.code3)) return false;

        return true;
    }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = code1.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + code2.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + code3.hashCode();
    return result;
}

}
```

iterate over object1 and populate object2. Once i had my object2 (now codeSymmary) populated. i could use the method below to do the job.

```
        Map<CodeKey, Double> summaryMap = summaries.parallelStream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CodeSummary::getKey,
                Collectors.summingDouble(CodeSummary::getAmount))); // summing the amount of grouped codes.
```

If anyone is using this as an example. then make sure you override the equal and hashcode function in your key object. else grouping will not work.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I get error using that. I need to group by String and summingDouble by Integer. Anyone knows how to do this.

Comment: I have Map<String, List<Report>> inside the Report is amount list.